# Mysql Group concat and subtraction values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-concat

I tried to calculate the difference in values ​​obtained from a mysql query where data values ​​are extracted in TIME format time laps of competition . the goal is to get the lap times between arrivals for each lap. This is the table `Times`.

```
id            number            time
---------+----------------+--------------------
1               9               00:00:02.000000
2               10              00:00:14.000000
3               9               00:11:09.000000
```

Mysql

```
SELECT 
    t.number, count(*) as laps, 
    group_concat(time order by t.id separator ',' ) as times, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`time`))) as total
FROM 
    times t
GROUP BY 
    number 
ORDER BY 
    laps DESC, total ASC
```

The output of this query is:

```
number        laps          times                     total
--------------------------------------------------------------
9              2           00:00:02,00:00:14         00:00:16.000000
10             1           00:11:09                  00:11:09.000000
```

Now, what I need is to get the length of time of each lap, WITH SUBTRACTIONS.
Any suggestion please. Thanks to this result:

```
number        laps          times                     total
--------------------------------------------------------------
9              2           00:00:02,00:00:12         00:00:14.000000
10             1           00:11:09                  00:11:09.000000
```

Comment: What `WITH SUBTRACTIONS` means? What does it mean from the domain logic perspective?

Comment: With Datediff or Timediff, for this case to obtain calculates  (00:00:14 - 00:00:02 ).... except first, like example

Comment: what if the first value is greater? Will it be a negative interval? What if there are 3 laps? Why do you subtract `14 - 2` not the other way around?

Comment: What I am trying to get are positive times, subtracting from right to left , and to obtain the difference , which would be the time for each lap

Comment: I don't understand 1 & 2 in the result. Perhaps the data set should be 9,9,10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have total times stored and want to calculate lap times. One way to do this is using a subquery;

```
SELECT t.number, COUNT(1) laps, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SEC_TO_TIME(time) ORDER BY t.id) times,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time)) total
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.number, 
    TIME_TO_SEC(t1.time) - COALESCE(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.time)), 0) time
  FROM times t1 
  LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t1.number = t2.number AND t2.id < t1.id
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
) t
GROUP BY number
```

The subquery calculates the lap times by subtracting all times for the same number with a smaller id from the total time for the end of each lap. The outer query does the formatting of the lap times in the format you're looking for.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a3fde/3).

Comment: Thanks Joachim ¡¡¡ is the solution: Thank you master